# Select box option based on text box value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code which change select option based on text box value but I want to change value of select option without click on "Select Now" button. Means select option change directly from text box value, button is not needed to do same.

```
<select name="sel" id="MySelect">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
</select><br><br>

Select By Text: <br>
<input type="text" name="selText" value="Six">
<input type="button" name="selectNow" value="Select Now">
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('input[name=selectNow]').on('click', function(event) {
        selectByText($.trim($('input[name=selText]').val()));
    }).click();
});

function selectByText(txt) {
    $('#MySelect option')
        .filter(function() { 
            return $.trim($(this).text()) == txt; 
        })
        .attr('selected', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is the same, except you need to hook to the `keyup` event on the `selText` element:

```
$('input[name=selText]').on('keyup', function() {
    selectByText($.trim($(this).val()));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w64ezakt/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the event to be raised when the value of `selText` changes:

```
$('input[name=selText]').on('change', function(event) {
    selectByText($.trim(this.value));
}).change();
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coptoe9a/2/)